# run new cygwin shell and kill it when I want

Tags: python, subprocess, cygwin

I've created an app that runs on cygwin, that will open some new shells and run python script on each of them. The problem started when I wanted to have control on the new shells and kill them at will. after a lot of digging I decided to use the following command:

`subprocess.run('mintty.exe -t {} -h always -e {} &'.format(app_name, run_app_cmd), shell = True)`

and later when I'll want to kill it use:

`subprocess.run('kill -2 {}'.format(apps[app].shell_pid), shell = True)`.

it worked pretty well until I realized that A-L-O-T of times the new terminal gets stuck and doesn't respond, and I don't like it. I made some more digging and I found that while I thought that the python on the current mintty executes the command and opens the new terminal, what that actually happens is that the windows host opens the new mintty (the PPID of the new terminal is 1), and then probably the signal goes through some windows problems and etc.
the reason that I want each of the scripts in a separate terminal is that each of them have a lot of output, and I want them in different windows.

Now, after all this explanation, is there any way to prevent this? I don't want these stuck to become a part of my life...

Comment: What do your python scripts do? Are they interactive, or do they just show some output. You could do `subprocess.run("python3 <script>.py" , shell=False)` and put `_ = input()` at the end of the script. You could use the same command with popen() (part of std python), and when you see an indication that the script is done on the process's stdout, send a blank line on the process's stdin. Also check the Process class in the multiprocessing package (part of std python lib), which might be the best solution.

Comment: the scripts are not interactive, but they have a lot of output and I want it seperated